# ViewData vs ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I read in one of the blogs as

> For ViewData while enumerating type conversion is required but ViewBag
>   since it is dynamic type conversion is not required

But we often say that ViewBag is a wrapper around ViewData, so how/why it is different when comes to type conversion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag is indeed a wrapper around ViewData, as you can see from the source code: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/62d0b2df0bcca848a8e0848fd1866928df15528e/src/System.Web.Mvc/ViewPage.cs. In both cases, the value is not strongly typed, so you need to cast it before using it, unless you want to use it as an object.